# Passing arguments to main and seeing if one string is in another in C?

Tags: c

So far I have a source code that passes arguments to main (if that's how I should call it) and it stores them into an array. My main problem is, how do I check if one argument is present in the other? It will make more sense when I write the code I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++) printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

So according to my C guide, it will store arguments including my program name in the first index 0 of argv.

Now here is my problem:

Lets say I have the string "hello world" in argv[1] and another string called "hello" in argv[2]. How do I check so that the string in argv[2] is in argv[1]? This problem is a subset problem I believe. Tips and guidance is much needed!

EDIT: I added the " " to my strings so that they don't break up when entered!

Comment: Check out the `strstr` function.

Comment: `hello world` will not stored in `argv` (two strings are there).

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to put in the "" so that the string won't break up when entered.

Comment: You are asking how to compare two strings. This has nothing to do with `main`, and has been asked countless times before.

Comment: you should use `%c` to print single character `printf("%c ", argv[i]);`

Comment: @Himanshu: wrong: `argv[i]` is a string of `char*` type so print it with `%s`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `argv` is a string but `argv[i]` will a single char value.

Comment: No, you are wrong, the second argument `argv` to `main` is *not* a string, but an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is in the `string.h` library.

Please try coding *something* with that library. If you still cannot get it to work, please update your question with your code.

Comment: Alright, I will try to find a tutorial and some documentation on this library.

Comment: Read [strstr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) and perhaps [strchr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)